# Why adding a class for "select-option" field makes "disabled" function not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I am working on a PHP project. After adding class `chosen-select` for the `<select>` field. The disable function does not working. If it is without the `chosen-select` class, it performed disabled function very well but there is no CSS style for the field anymore. Is there any expert who is willing to give some valuable comment to me?

Here is my code:

```
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                <div class="field-holder">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Restaurant Name', 'foodbakery' ) ?>" name="search_title" id="search_rest" onkeyup="disableDropDown()" value="<?php echo esc_html( $search_title ) ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                <div class="field-holder">
                    <div class="select-holder">
                        <select data-placeholder="" class="chosen-select" id="search_cusine" name="search_cusine" onchange="disableTextField()">
                            <?php
                            global $foodbakery_plugin_options;
                            $selected_fileds = isset( $foodbakery_plugin_options['default_cousins_list'] ) ? $foodbakery_plugin_options['default_cousins_list'] : '';
                            foreach ( $selected_fileds as $val ) {
                                $restaurant_type_cate = get_term_by( 'slug', $val, 'restaurant-category' );
                                echo '<option value='. esc_html( $restaurant_type_cate->name ) .'>' . esc_html( $restaurant_type_cate->name ) . '</option>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>

                        <script>
                            function disableDropDown() {
                                var x = document.getElementById("search_rest").value;
                                if (x != ''){
                                    document.getElementById("search_cusine").disabled= true;

                                }
                                else{
                                    document.getElementById("search_cusine").disabled = false;
                                }
                            }
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: By adding this class you are triggering the functionality of https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/, which hides your `select` element and replaces it with a custom HTML structure to achieve the desired formatting. Only disabling your “original” select likely won’t do therefor, so you need to go and check the documentation for this plugin to find out how to disabled such a “modified” select field correctly.

Comment: Are you using [Chosen (jquery plugin)](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)? If so, check [this comment in issues](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/67#issuecomment-2170256)

Comment: @CBroe I went through and tried your suggestions. However, they did not work. document.getElementById("search_cusine").disabled= true; is work if it is not put into the function disableDropDown().

Comment: @barbsan I went through and tried your suggestions. However, they did not work. document.getElementById("search_cusine").disabled= true; is work if it is not put into the function disableDropDown().

Comment: Is `disableDropDown` called on change event after adding `class="chosen-select"`?

Comment: @barbsan the disableDropDown function is called by the input text field. Is onkeyup a good way to call disableDropDown?